# How to use phpunit with php4 code

Tags: php, phpunit

I have the following example test code (PHP4) I need to run with `phpunit`:

```
<?php

require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';

class RemoteConnectTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  public function setUp(){ }
  public function tearDown(){ }
  public function testConnectionIsValid()
  {
    $this->assertTrue(true);
  }
}
?>
```

which does not run with `phpunit`:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Framework.php' ...
```

How do I need to setup my environment to make this work (Linux, Ubuntu 12.04)? Do I need to set a search path? Change `php.ini`? I AM NOT ABLE TO CHANGE THE TEST CODE ITSELF.

Comment: Does the required file stay in the right relative path?

Comment: I need the given code example to work without change. I can change paths, `phpunit`, use options, anything, but the test code has to stay unchanged. Where all the required files are is of no importance.

Comment: Your code will not work, if your required files are in different than the mentioned path, isn't it obvious?

Comment: So how to fix the problem then? I do not know where `PHPUnit/Framework.php` is at all...

Comment: Don't you have root access?

Comment: I have root access. But how to solve my problem? I would prefer a solution to include the PHP search path to the PHPUnit files somehow. How to do that?

Comment: If you don't, but you have access for commit/merge/create, you can create PHPUnit directory and download the Framework class from PHP Unit's website, and upload in PHPUnit directory. Look at this -> http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase

Comment: You have root access, so you should search where the whole framework is installed. Or reinstall it, in the directory where you are creating the test cases, since you don't want to (why?!) change the code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28367/discussion-between-alex-and-royal-bg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is an incompatibility between the used versions. Newer versions of `phpunit` do have a different internal setup ([see example for 3.7 here](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html)) which are different from older `phpunit` versions.

One need to 'downgrade' `phpunit`, as example as follows:

```
sudo pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit
sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit-3.2.8
```

to install version 3.2.8, for example. It can be verified the existance of the file `Framework.php`:

```
> ls /usr/share/php/PHPUnit
Extensions  Framework  Framework.php  Runner  TextUI  Util
```

The example code should work now when called as

```
phpunit SimpleTest.php
```

(assuming identical name of class and file [excluding the `php` of course]).

Answer (score 0):

Since you can run phpunit from command line, you most likely have the source code installed with PEAR already (or composer, which is less likely). But path to framework is not in global include paths (or in system variable PATH).

The path to PHPUnit is usually inside PEAR. And PEAR is usually near php installation. You can always use global filesearch in terminal with

`find / -name 'Framework.php' 2>/dev/null`

You either need to either

- edit php.ini and add path to PHPUnit in include_path directive
- require_once absolute path
- use autoloading (but thats only from PHP 5.3)

Comment: There is no `Framework.php` file at all. It is completely missing!!